# Brew List and Install Specific Versions of Formula

Tags: homebrew, homebrew-cask

I would like to install 2.6.X but cannot find documentation on how to specify a formula version.  Brew is only installing the latest version of the formula.

I'm using the following versions of brew

```
Homebrew 1.8.6
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 5ea559; last commit 2018-12-18)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 4144b74; last commit 2018-12-18)
```

I'm upgrading from 2.2.1 and want to be pinned to 2.6.X

```
ls /usr/local/Cellar/ansible
2.2.1.0_2   2.3.1.0     2.7.5

brew search ansible
==> Formulae
ansible ✔                                 ansible-cmdb                              
ansible-lint                              ansible@1.9                               
ansible@2.0                               terraform-provisioner-ansible 
==> Casks
ansible-dk

brew install ansible

ansible --version
ansible 2.7.5
```

If someone could point me to the correct docs at https://docs.brew.sh/ to both list all available versions and to install specific versions that would be awesome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to the directory containing formulas:

```
cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula
```

Look at the history of the ansible formula

```
git log -- ansible.rb
```

Select the commit where the version you are interested in is and checkout this formula:

```
git checkout f9466d14ee6e9fa7a -- ansible.rb
```

Install that formula:

```
HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew install ansible
```

Check the installation of ansible:

```
ansible --version
```

Pin this version of the formula to avoid upgrade

```
brew pin ansible
```

That's it, an I'm not sure that this is in the documentation.

Comment: Perfect!  This worked like a charm.

One thing I had to do before installing the formula was unlinking my current ansible formula

`brew unlink ansible`